# Identify Continuous Periods of Time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Today my issue has to do with marking continuous periods of time where a given criteria is met. My raw data of interest looks like this.

```
Salesman ID        Pay Period ID         Total Commissionable Sales (US dollars)
 1                    101                       525
 1                    102                       473
 1                    103                       672
 1                    104                       766 
 2                    101                       630
 2                    101                       625
 .....
```

I want to mark continous periods of time where a salesman has achieved $500 of sales or more. My ideal result should look like this.

```
[Salesman ID]    [Start time]     [End time]    [# Periods]    [Average Sales]
      1             101              101          1               525
      1             103              107          5               621   
      2             101              103          3               635
      3             104              106          3               538
```

I know how to everything else, but I cannot figure out a non-super expensive way to identify start and end dates. Help!

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this is a hard problem in SQL.  You can do an "iterative" solution using a recursive CTE.  If the problem were to break the rows into groups of *exactly* 500, then you could do it wiht windowing functions.

Comment: Yeah ..Most of the solutions I can think of takes many many iterations. Might be ill just copy this in Excel and write an iterative macro to muscle through it

Comment: Do you only care about the first $500 or increments of $500?  If the first, then there is a solution.  The problem is increments of $500.

Comment: . . I don't see how the results relate to the sample data.  The numbers do not add up in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. The innermost select-statement basically adds a new column to the original table with a flag determining when a new group begins. Outside this statement, we use this flag in a running total, that then enumerates the groups - we call this column [Group ID]. All that is left, is then to filter out the rows where [Sales] < 500, and group by [Salesman ID] and [Group ID].

```
SELECT [Salesman ID], MIN([Pay Period ID]) AS [Start time],
    MAX([Pay Period ID]) AS [End time], COUNT(*) AS [# of periods],
    AVG([Sales]) AS [Average Sales]
FROM (
    SELECT [Salesman ID], [Pay Period ID], [Sales],
        SUM(NewGroup) OVER (PARTITION BY [Salesman ID] ORDER BY [Pay Period ID]
                            ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS [Group ID]
    FROM (
        SELECT T1.*,
            CASE WHEN T1.[Sales] >= 500 AND (Prev.[Sales] < 500 OR Prev.[Sales] IS NULL)
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [NewGroup]
        FROM MyTable T1
        LEFT JOIN MyTable Prev ON Prev.[Salesman ID] = T1.[Salesman ID] 
                               AND Prev.[Pay Period ID] = T1.[Pay Period ID] - 1
    ) AS InnerQ
) AS MiddleQ
WHERE [Sales] >= 500
GROUP BY [Salesman ID], [Group ID]
```